# Enforce Visual Studio "Code-Format Rules" via Domain Policy?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, there are formatting rules found in the options menu that specify things such as where to include line breaks, how many spaces to use when tabbing (or to use tabs instead of spaces, etc.)

Is there a way to push these rules to each programmer's machine using a domain policy or some other way?

Comment: Looking for something simlar, so would be good to know how anyone else has enforced fxCop, etc. in all solutions being created by a team.

Comment: Paul, just make Code Analysis part of your build: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668977.aspx

Comment: I still have not found a graceful solution to this. I did find out where Studio stores the "style preferences" of code in the registry. I guess the solution would be to find someway to push those reg settings out to each person when they login to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't actually rules -- they're preferences for automatic formatting applied by the IDE as you type.  You can share those preferences by exporting them from one VS instance and importing them into another, but no amount of preference application will actually verify the contents of edited files.

If you want to actually apply rules regarding code formatting, you might want to consider using a tool like [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phphosts.org/2010/05/share-the-same-visual-studio-settings-between-team-members/

That does not necessarily ENFORCE things though. You might have to do that in a login script after you figure out where those settings go.